# jQuery Mobile Breaks OmniAuth

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, omniauth

I realize the framework is in alpha but implementing [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) has broken my omniauth authentication. When I try to sign in jQuery mobile spits out a general error message as soon as I try to hit the /auth/twitter controller.

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? What is the error message exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem and it's because the auth/:provider link needs to have `rel='external'` on the anchor tag otherwise jquery mobile will try and treat it as an ajax link.

Another problem I recently encountered is that Facebook's oauth callback wasn't working. The short answer is that it puts some garbage after the hash in the url `something.com/#_=_`. All you need to do is get rid of that and you're good to go. Specifics and the long answer can be found at the bottom of this page: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Comment: This is a fine solution, and I used it as well, but the problem is that if you're trying to get your jQuery Mobile app to behave more like a native app on iOS the rel="external" causes the app to pop over to Safari and the redirect remains in the new browser window instead of within the "app" chrome.

All the time I've spent fighting these little issues I could have written the iOS app by now :)

Comment: Are you running your app outside of the browser? Have you wrapped it into a native app?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"data-ajax" => false` to the link.